# Python split equally

Tags: python

This might be silly. I cannot figure it out right now.

There is a total number (x)

Which needs to be divided equally with (y)

If x is 10,000 and y is 10,

That would mean 10,000 is to be spit between 10.

How to find the starting point as

```
1 starts at 1 and ends 1,000
2 starts at 1,001 & ends 2,000
3 ..
4 ..
5 ..
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is really just some simple maths:

```py
x = 10000
y = 10
print([(item, item+(x//y-1)) for item in range(1, x, x//y)])
```

Gives us:

```
[(1, 1000), (1001, 2000), (2001, 3000), (3001, 4000), (4001, 5000), (5001, 6000), (6001, 7000), (7001, 8000), (8001, 9000), (9001, 10000)]
```

Here we use [the `range()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) and a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY).

This works by using the `range()` builtin to construct a generator from `1` to below `x`, taking steps of `x` divided (integer division, so we don't get a floating point number) by `y`.

We then use a list comprehension to take these values (`1, 1001, 2001, ..., 9001`) and then put them into tuple pairs, adding `(x//y-1)` (in this case `999`) to the value to get the ending boundary.

Naturally, if you want to use this in a loop, for example, you would be better off with a generator expression so that it's evaluated lazily, over a list comprehension. E.g:

```py
>>> for number, (start, end) in enumerate((item, item+(x//y-1)) for item in range(1, x, x//y)): 
...     print(number, "starts at", start, "and ends at", end)
... 
0 starts at 1 and ends at 1000
1 starts at 1001 and ends at 2000
2 starts at 2001 and ends at 3000
3 starts at 3001 and ends at 4000
4 starts at 4001 and ends at 5000
5 starts at 5001 and ends at 6000
6 starts at 6001 and ends at 7000
7 starts at 7001 and ends at 8000
8 starts at 8001 and ends at 9000
9 starts at 9001 and ends at 10000
```

Comment: There seems to be a weird problem with this site, it thinks that `//` is a comment in python.

Comment: `<pre>` tag can be used instead of 4-indentation to disable syntax highlighting.

Comment: Did you mean to write `(x\\y-1)` - typo?

Comment: It's  `//` or floor division. Google's prettify has deduced the wrong language based on the snippet. See:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/stackoverflow-syntax-highlighting

Comment: @BlaXpirit I fixed by declaring it to be Python explicitly.

Comment: @Lattyware sorry, probably related to how the site treats the // vs \\ used in your last line of your answer

Comment: @Levon No, it was a typo, just I didn't see it. Dunno how I managed to type that, thanks for the spot. It should always be forward slashes for integer division.